# MongoDB C++ driver query error

Tags: c++, mongodb

The MongoDB C++ driver is doing my head in. I have a working driver that works fine for all queries except the one below, which stops program compilation.

The code should work according to MongoDB documentation here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/cpp-to-sql-to-mongo-shell/

The intention is to select just the "name" field of all documents in a collection.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace mongo;

DBClientConnection c;
c.connect("localhost");

auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("db.coll", Query(), 0, 0, BSON("name" << 1));

//auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("db.coll", Query().sort("_id", -1), 0, 0);
//auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("db.coll", Query());
//auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("db.coll", QUERY("type" << "blog"));
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘mongo::DBClientConnection::query(const char [19], mongo::Query, int, int, mongo::BSONObj)’
mongodriver/include/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:1274: note: candidates are:       virtual std::auto_ptr<mongo::DBClientCursor> mongo::DBClientConnection::query(const std::string&, mongo::Query, int, int, const mongo::BSONObj*, int, int)
```

I have tried everything I can think of to make the call parameters match the suggested candidate, but only succeed in generating different errors.
Note that the commented out queries all work fine. Frustrating.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

@mjhall,

I believe you are right in pointing that the mentioned query does not work. The c.query() expects a *BSONObj** while the example is passing a *BSONObj*. Can you try following and see if that works for you?

```
DBClientConnection c;
c.connect("localhost");

BSONObj b = BSON("name" << 1);
auto_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = c.query("db.coll", Query(), 0, 0, &b);
```

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the problem. I'd vote you up but don't have the necessary rep, sorry!